# when transfer object to json, with gson api "toJson", sometimes the time cost is much longer than usual

Tags: java, json, gson

I use gson in my program to transfer object to json, everything works. But when I do the performance test, I found that sometimes "toJson(Object)" cost much longer than usual. For example, usually, the transfer takes less than 1ms. When I invoke this method for 1000 times, there are several times the transfer takes 3 or 5ms, or even more than 10ms. During this period, I checked the tomcat GC log, no minor gc or full gc happened.
simplify the program into the following format:

```
for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
...
method1();
method2();
...  
long stamp1 =System.currentTimeMillis(); 
string msg = gson.toJson(object);   
long stamp2 =System.currentTimeMillis(); 
system.out.println(stamp2-stamp1); 
log.info(msg);
...
}
```

Comment: and how do your test looks like?

Comment: just like ```for(i=0;i<1000;i++) { ...  long stamp1 =System.currentTimeMillis(); gson.toJson(object);   long stamp2 =System.currentTimeMillis(); system.out.println(stamp2-stamp1); ...}```

Comment: Is the output significantly bigger than your average output? Could it be that other threads or even processes hog the CPU?

Comment: The server is 4C16G, and my program is not complicated, I use top command to monitor cpu, it only reach 20%. And the outputs are almost the same